# Invoke Ansible playbook in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, ansible

I have jenkins build and I am trying to invoke a ansible playbook file for an s3 upload. When I execute a post-build-script for invoking an ansible playbook file, I am ending with below error.
**Cannot run program "ansible-playbook" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mybuild"): error=2, No such file or directory**

Below screenshot is ansible post build script configuration.
[image]

FYI: There is a file(ansibledemo.yml) in my build folder. I tried giving absolute path(/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mybuild/ansibledemo.yml). Still no go.

**When I try running ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml directly in jenkins image(terminal) I am ending up with *bash: ansible-playbook: command not found***

When I tried installing ansible in my jenkins server, I couldn't execute any installation commands. Please see the below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I suspect there is problem with search path to ansible-playbook itself...

Comment: can you try ${WORKSPACE}/mybuild/ansibledemo.yml or ${WORKSPACE}/ansibledemo.yml

Comment: @ArbabNazar I have edited my question. Even if I running playbook file directly in jenkins cmd, I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is not install on your Jenkins machine, first you need to install the ansible on the jenkins machine:

**On Ubuntu/Debian:**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
```

**On CentOS/RedHat:**

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install ansible
```

After that you will be able to run the ansible-playbook.

Comment: I have updated my question. Whenever I try installing in my jenkins server, I am ending up with **command not found** error.

Comment: jenkins is not a sudo user, you need to login as root or the user that have sudo privileges

Comment: I am running jenkins in docker container. Is that the reason I couldn't execute any commands ? If Yes/No, can you show some thoughts here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install using pip version as an alternative and try, Please see the below steps,

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install ansible-container[docker,openshift]
```

You can see more options to install in docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/installation.html

But always it is a good option to keep a separate vm / docker like "ansible-controller" and use that as a slave to jenkins, So that you don't need ansible plugins in ansible. And jenkins will be always stable  without much load

Answer (score 0):

1. Download package information from the configured sources.

   `# apt update`
2. Install ansible

   `# apt install ansible`

That's it.

If you run official jenkins container (based on debian) than repo with ansible build in already and you don't need "apt-add-repository". But you could install apt-add-repository by installing software-properties-common for further using.

`dpkg -S apt-add-repository` tells that this packet belongs to software-properties-common.

Error appears because the author of container always tries to make it as light as possible and remove package information.

You don't need sudo, because you become root in container by default. You become another user only if you mention it in intentionally.

Please, add information that you work in container to your question.