# Executing Ansible Playbook using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, ansible

I know there's a related question here: [Invoke Ansible playbook in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771060/invoke-ansible-playbook-in-jenkins?rq=1)

But this question is different from that in some perspectives:

So I have Jenkins and Ansible installed in a single server (EC2 instance). I have created a playbook.yml which copies files from this server to another server. This is successful if I do ansible-playbook playbook.yml using ec2-user.

The same if I try to do using Jenkins (Created a project and added a build step as run ansible playbook and mentioned the location of playbook.yml and running as sudo ec2-user). This is failing with the error:

```
fatal: [172.xx.xx.xx]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/Host_Keypair.pem: Permission denied\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ansible/copy.retr
```

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: 172.xx.xx.xx
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
   - copy:
     src: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ansible/myfile.conf
     dest: /etc/myfile.conf
     owner: ec2-user
     group: ec2-user
     mode: 0644
```

I am stuck on this and not able to move to next step without executing this. Can anyone please help me on what other configuration I am missing (possibly in Jenkins side). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playbook is executed under `jenkins` user which doesn't have access to `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/Host_Keypair.pem` key on ansible/jenkins host to authenticate on remote server.

There is an error message:

> no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/Host_Keypair.pem: Permission denied

Comment: So what do you suggest as a solution? I believe jenkins user is not a login user, rather its a service account if I am not wrong.

Comment: Fix permission issue, so `jenkins` user can read ssh-key required to connect to remote host. For example, copy `Host_Keypair.pem` somewhere and `chown` as `jenkins`.

Comment: Instead of copying, can I chown jenkins to the original pem file? Would that be a best way?

Comment: This way you'll lose ability to ssh as `ec2-user`, because ssh keys should have `0600` permissions and accessible only by one user (owner).

Comment: okies.. let me try then... Now I shall copy the pem file to some other location and chown jenkins. What should be the permission here?